# reading a json file in ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

this is the tree of my workplace. I'm getting an error while trying to read my resume.json file.

```
.
├── lib
│   ├── resume.json
│   └── resume.rb
└── spec
    ├── resume_spec.rb
    └── spec_helper.rb
```

this file (resume.rb) is working perfectly on this call (`ruby resume.rb`)

file resume.rb

```
require "json"

class Resume
  attr_accessor :name, :tel, :email, :experience, :education, :company

  def initialize
    file = File.read("resume.json")
    data = JSON.parse(file)
    @name = data.first.last
  end

end

resume = Resume.new
puts resume.name.size
```

but when I'm running the spec I'm getting this error

```
.../resume.rb:7:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - resume.json (Errno::ENOENT)
```

file resume_spec.rb

```
require "spec_helper"
require_relative "../lib/resume"


describe Resume do 

  before :each do
    @resume = Resume.new 
  end

  it "#Resume" do
     expect(@resume).to be_an_instance_of(Resume)
  end

  it "response to attribute" do
    expect(@resume).to respond_to(:name)
    expect(@resume).to respond_to(:tel)
    expect(@resume).to respond_to(:email)
    expect(@resume).to respond_to(:experience)
    expect(@resume).to respond_to(:education)
    expect(@resume).to respond_to(:company)
  end
  it "name should be my name" do
    expect(@resume.name).to eq("hello")
  end

end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`File("resume.json")` reads the file relative to the *current working directory*, which translates to from where you are running the code.

In order for you to read the file, when you know where it is *relative to the code*, you should use [`expand_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-expand_path):

```
File.read(File.expand_path("resume.json", __FILE__))
```